# PHP generated SQL Checkboxes - Select / Insert and Delete based on checked

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a little trouble with the below

(apologies for it being so messy)

I am creating a PHP generated set of check boxes, which i'm passing the variants over to the update_records.php page (below) as values "val1-val2" then splitting them out and trying to check the database if they exist, and if not add the record. All works great, minus the part i can't get my head round - how to delete records when a user unticks a checkbox and then submits.. Anyone able to help?

```
if(isset($_POST['variants']) && !empty($_POST['variants'])) {

    $arr_variants = $_POST['variants'];
   foreach($arr_variants as $variant) {

    $storevariants = explode('-', $variant); 

    $baseid = $storevariants[0]; 
    $colourid = $storevariants[1];

  $sql_finalcheck = "SELECT * FROM finalproducts WHERE asset_id = $post_asset_id AND colour_id = $colourid AND base_id = $baseid";

  $result = $conn->query($sql_finalcheck);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "record already exists"; // just to show a message to show how its handling the data.
    }

     else {
$sql_add_vars = "INSERT INTO finalproducts (asset_id, colour_id, base_id) VALUES ('$post_asset_id', '$colourid', '$baseid')";
if ($conn->query($sql_add_vars) === TRUE) {

     }    }    }         }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn all the checked boxes into a list that you can check with `NOT IN`:

```
if(isset($_POST['variants']) && !empty($_POST['variants'])) {

    $arr_variants = $_POST['variants'];
    $arr_notin = array();
    foreach($arr_variants as $variant) {

        $storevariants = explode('-', $variant); 

        $baseid = intval($storevariants[0]); 
        $colourid = intval($storevariants[1]);
        $arr_notin[] = "($baseid, $colourid)";

        $sql_finalcheck = "SELECT * FROM finalproducts WHERE asset_id = $post_asset_id AND colour_id = $colourid AND base_id = $baseid";

        $result = $conn->query($sql_finalcheck);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "record already exists"; // just to show a message to show how its handling the data.
        }

        else {
            $sql_add_vars = "INSERT INTO finalproducts (asset_id, colour_id, base_id) VALUES ('$post_asset_id', '$colourid', '$baseid')";
            if ($conn->query($sql_add_vars) === TRUE) {
            }
        }
    }
    $str_notin = implode(", ", $arr_notin);
    $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM finalproducts WHERE asset_id = $post_asset_id AND (baseid, colourid) NOT IN ($str_notin)";
    $conn->query($sql_delete));
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - thanks so much - i spent a while trying to work out how to go about it - tried putting DELETE's just before inserting - but ended up spending hours and getting no where. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another option would be to use radio buttons, with names like `variant[<baseid>-<colorid>]` and values `add` and `delete`. You could then loop through all these, either inserting or deleting depending on which value was selected.